# Lightswitch Beta 2 Not connecting to .\SQLExpress

Tags: silverlight, sql-server-express, visual-studio-lightswitch, user-instance

Hi Has anyone used LightSwitch Beta 2. Well I installed this LightSwitch beta 2 on VS2010 SP 1

Now I am getting the following error with the project build.

> An error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server instance
>   '.\SQLEXPRESS'. The user instance
>   login flag is not supported on this
>   version of SQL Server. The connection
>   will be closed. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\LightSwitch\v1.0\Microsoft.LightSwitch.targets

One difference I have, I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on my machine. Before installing this R2 LightSwitch beta 1 (few months back) was working.

Now what I have done so far is gone to the roots of the all config file where there is a reference to .\SQLExpress modified it to use a full instance name and user name and set the "User Instance=false" Yet I am getting this error from build.

Anyone get any idea?

(I can't un-install SQL 2008 R2 - too much going on in there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to debug and develop LightSwitch applications, SQL Express must be used. Beth Massi explains why in the following thread.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitchgeneral/thread/de2e7ee5-fc82-4614-9245-4f4a9ae7185f

If you still receive the error 'The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server' when connecting to SQL Express, the following SQL can be used to switch on the user login instance flag.

EXEC sp_configure 'user instances enabled', 1
GO
Reconfigure
GO